# Why is My Zombified Piglin Texture Not Saving / Reverting Zombie Pigman

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am working on a texture pack which I will be submitting to MCPEDL. It is called "The Splashing Blazes", where basically I am changing the looks of the Nether. I edited the Zombie Piglin file and put it in the right folder but when I loaded the world to test it out, not only did it not save my textures, but it was the model of the old Zombie Piglin. Any idea how to fix this?

I looked it up and could not find anything:
[image: Plus more]

Comment: did you swap to the texture pack?

Comment: yes. I equipped the texture pack in 2 different worlds. Same thing.

Comment: Can you tell us the file's directory?

Comment: games, com.mojang, resource packs, the splashing blazes, textures, entity, piglin